# How to do matrix derivative calculation?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

For example, the derivative $W^{T}AW$ with respect to $W$ is $2AW$.

Is there any general guidelines or rules that we can follow?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Einstein notation:

$(W^{T}AW)_{ij} = W_{ki}A_{kl}W_{lj}$

All you gotta do is take the derivative with respect to $W_{mn}$ , considering that $\frac{\partial W_{ij}}{\partial W_{mn}} = \delta_{im}\delta_{jn}$ , where I'm summing over repeated indices and $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta. Careful with the order of the indices.

The rest I leave to you. Good luck.